# I want to save the changes made in html page in that session so that when I reload it those changes should remain same. Any way to do that using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a local HTML page on that I run a javascript by a button which changes a few elements attribute in HTML I want these changes to remain the same even when I reload it How to do that using javascript or any other way?

```html
// put your HTML code in here
```

Comment: edit your question and put your HTML code in here, please.

Answer (score 0):

Using JS, you save all the changes you want to be able to restore in a cookie or a local/session storage, let's call it state. Then on page load you analyze your state and restore it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

As what [BNazaruk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3700993/bnazaruk) has pointed out, store your state in the browser's local storage or session storage, then retrieve these stored states everytime the user reloads the page.